# Filtering a nested list without using a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter, nested

Hi does anyone know if I can filter a nested list to return only the second value in each sub-list?  I can do it using a for-loop, just wondering if it possible to use the filter method?

```
weather_data = [['1', 'sunny'], ['2', 'rainy'], ['3', 'sunny']]
```

return:

```
weather = ['sunny', 'rainy', 'sunny']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about to use a list comprehension:

```
values = [x[1] for x in weather_data]
print (values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the snake_case you have chosen in your question implies Python, try `map` function:

```
weather_data = [['1', 'sunny'], ['2', 'rainy'], ['3', 'sunny']]
result = list(map(lambda x: x[1], weather_data))
print(result)
```

If not Python, plenty of other languages have this functionality in slightly different syntaxes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)#Language_comparison